# Unknown option "–disable-shared" when trying to build ffmpeg with NVIDIA hardware acceleration support on Windows

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia

Following the docs here: https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/ffmpeg-with-nvidia-gpu/

Within the mingw64 environment, I have navigated to the ffmpeg directory and executed the following command:

> ./configure --enable-nonfree –disable-shared --enable-cuda-nvcc
> --enable-libnpp –-toolchain=msvc --extra-cflags=-I../nv_sdk --extra-ldflags=-libpath:../nv_sdk

Unfortunately, this outputs the following:

> Unknown option "–disable-shared". See ./configure --help for available
> options.

I tried to skip to the next step and see if this error was just a warning that could be ignored, but executing `make -j 8` from the mingw64.exe environment produces the following output:

> Makefile:180: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory make: *** No
> rule to make target '/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.

Clearly, I am having trouble building a version of ffmpeg that supports nVidia hardware acceleration.  I am wondering if their docs have become outdated possibly.

Is there a binary available that lets me skip this step?  Alternatively, is there a way to use GPU hardware acceleration for encoding with the standard windows ffmpeg build?

I am pretty new to this binary...thank you.

Comment: Not to stop you from building the project, as far as I know and experienced, Gyan's builds already comes with cuda/nvenc/nvdec support [Linke](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/#libraries)

Comment: @Linke Thanks, found that out recently.  Does spare me from having to do this, but am not seeing a performance gain from the following command:  ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -t 00:30:00 -vcodec h264_nvenc out.mp4.  Using the default video encoder produces the same FPS for encoding, which is a problem.  But, it does give a huge performance increase when looping a video file n times (not stream_loop, since that does not rencode and is inherently very fast).

Answer (score 2):

You missed a dash in `–disable-shared`, so it's `-–disable-shared`.

In any case, the bottleneck in your encoding op is the continuous image decode forced by `-loop` option. Instead, use the loop filter.

```
ffmpeg -i image.jpg -vf loop=-1:1:0 -t 00:30:00 -vcodec h264_nvenc out.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The missing dash is also in nVidia's docs.  However, I tried with 2 dashes because I noticed that as well and the error still occurred.  Regardless I found that I don't need to build this myself, since your windows build already supports h264_nvenc/nvdec.

Thanks for letting me know about the bottleneck, as well.